# Static methods may only be declared on a type

Tags: swift

I am getting an error that says:

> Static methods may only be declared on a type

How can I solve this ?

```
public static func random(min min: CGFloat, max: CGFloat) -> CGFloat {

    return CGFloat.random() * (max - min) + min
}
```

This is how I am calling the above method from the SWIFT class.

```
var ran = CGFloat.random(min:-255, max:588)
```

Comment: Isn't a static method another name for a type method? So "Type methods can only be declared on a type" seems to make sense. What problem are you having?

Comment: I am a bit of a newbie here. Can you elaborate please. @SteveIves

Comment: If you want `random(min:max:)` to be a type method on `CGFloat`, then you need to define it in a `CGFloat` extension.

Comment: @Illep - a type method is what would be called a class method in another OO language - it's a method that doesn't have to be associated with a particular instance of a class. E.g. the CGFloat method random doesn't act upon a particular CGFloat, thus is a class or type method and you don;t have to have instantiated a CGFloat to use it. Instance methods will need an instance of the type upon which the function is called.

Comment: @Hamish - you're right - I already had a set of Swift extensions with random defined as an extension to CGFloat.

Comment: Thanks. Understood.

Answer (score 26):

The reason I got this error message in a slightly confusing place was that **I had a missing close parenthesis earlier in the class**.

To the compiler the declaration seemed to be inside another method. For this reason the error message showed up in a place that seemed otherwise to be fine. Error message it self is on point.

This was the first google hit, so I'm adding my experience here in the hopes it will help others who have made a similar mess.

Comment: This saved me :)

Answer (score 7):

I got the same error due to **extra closing parentheses** in the former `class`.

[image]

Answer (score 5):

A lot of answers seem to be resolving around typos and extra scopes left open or prematurely closed. However, just for the case if some people will meet this issue while deliberately trying to declare **a function in global scope** as `static`, a clarification needs to be made:

All functions in global scope are statically linked inside the executable/library, which is a reason why they are available globally, from any scope, in the first place. However, in the context of an object oriented language, which Swift, undoubtedly, is, the allocation of instances of classes is by design allowed (and expected) to be dynamic, so the actual memory address at which the instance will end up being allocated is unknown ahead of time. So that's what we do - we declare functions as static to explicitly tell the compiler that while this function belongs to this class, it needs to be not bound to a particular instance of class, but the class itself, thus allowing for it being accessed from anywhere. In this regard, we could say that all functions in global scope are implicitly static.